# NEI wont give me items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In Not Enough Items mod, when I click on a item: with recipe it shows the recipe. If the item does not have a recipe it does nothing. When I try to drag items into my inventory nothing happens.

I have gone into notepad and set `lockmode=1` and `cheatmode=2` but it is already there. I am in the global setting on cheat mode. What else can I do? I just wanted to cheat in spanwers for a creative world. Is there a solution to this problem or a way to get vanilla/modded spawners?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Option in the NEI settings which you can access from your Inventory, I don't remember in which exact menu it was but it should give you the Option to switch between "Recipe Mode" "Utility Mode" and "Cheat Mode", changing into Cheat Mode should make you able to get the Spawners.

Comment: This is right, it's in the Inventory section of the menu. Which is under options in the bottom left hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly confusing, but you need to set the Cheat mode for the World, not the Global one.

In the inventory option menu, click on the "Global" button on the top right of the screen to change it to "World", and then set the mode to "Cheat"